# How can I return multiple function values in a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise, callback

I am crawling 5 different sites for data using node-fetch and cheerio.
everything checks out but I need to collect the returned data from these 5 separate functions in an array.

First I store function name and url for each site in an object like so

````
    url: 'https://sampleurl.com',
    crawl: FirstLinkCrawl
}

const secondLink = {
    url: 'https://sampleurl.com',
    crawl: secondLinkCrawl
}
}```

Then I write the function to crawl each site like so, I ran this function with and without promise, both check out


```const secondLinkCrawl = (body) =>{
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
    "this crawl function is ran here, everything works fine, Data is an object"
        const error = false
        if(!error){
            res(Data)
        }else{
            rej()
        }
    })         
}```

This here is my fetch function that takes the url and a callback, which is the crawl function 

```async function Fetch(url, callback){
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const html = await response.text()
    callback(html)
}
````

Then I call the fetch and crawl using promise.all() in an attempt to have it return in an array, but in an array,

```
    const promises = [
     Fetch(firstLink.url, firstLink.crawl), 
     Fetch(secondLink.url, secondLink.crawl)]

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(values => console.log(values))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

When I run this, I get `[ undefined, undefined ]`
But when I run it without promises and simply log the result, both of them run successfully.
My aim is to get my results in a single array. what can I do?

I also tried declaring an array a the top of the page and then pushing each result into the array, after which I log the array at the bottom of the functions call. But the array returns empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from Fetch function that's why it's undefined. You can fix it by -

```
async function Fetch(url, callback){
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const html = await response.text()
    const result = await callback(html);
    return result;
}
```

As the callback, you are passing in Fetch function returns Promise so we can await it and return the result